# Check if certain content exists in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Table with 3 Fields: the first is the `id` (auto increment), the second is called `markerID` (String) and the third `score` (Integer).

I want to add a new line if the current `markerID` of the activity does not already exist in the Table.

The Problem is, as the cursor goes through the entries and there is already an entry that has not the current `markerID`, it adds a new one for every different markerID stored in the table even if it shoudn't because the current markerID already exists.

How can I check if the `markerID` doesn't exist at all instead of just asking if it does not equal the current `markerID`?

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Log.d("Database", "Inhalt: "+ cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1));

                    if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)) < 5 && cursor.getString(1).equals(markerID)) {
                    /*markerID exists: Update Entry*/
                        dbh.updateScore(dbh, Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), markerID, score);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (!cursor.getString(1).equals(markerID) ){
                        /*markerID does not exist in Table: add new, but not for every entry where it does not equal to the current!*/
                        dbh.addScore(dbh, score, markerID);
                        finish();
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
           }
            else {
                /*Add first entry*/
                dbh.addScore(dbh, score, markerID);
                finish();
            }
```

This is how I generate the cursor in my `DbHelper` class:

```
 public Cursor getScore(DbHelper dbh) {
    dbase = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
    String columns[] = {COLUMN_SCORE, COLUMN_MARKERID};
    Cursor cursor = dbase.query(SCORE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

has a parameter 'selection', where you can put your markerID. Something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = dbase.query(SCORE_TABLE, columns, "markerId = 'your string'", null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    // you have rows with this marker id
}
```

Comment: A valid answer but worth noting that it is best practice to use a ? placeholder in the selection and provide the value in the selectionArgs parameter. Also known as a parameterised query. This avoids the risk of SQL injection and invalid SQL being generated where the value might contain characters such as quotes and apostrophes. For example: dbase.query(SCORE_TABLE, columns, "markerId = ?", new String[] {"your string"}, null, null, null)